# Adwords and Double-click: possible to have interactive banner ads where you click multiple times within the ad before being redirected to a website?

Tags: google-ads-api, interactive, double-click, banner-ads

I have a client who is requesting something that I don't think is possible, but wanted to verify before I tell them it can't be done. What they want: to create an interactive animated banner ad, where the user would click on the ad to attempt to shoot a basket though a basketball goal. They will miss the first one, but try again, then make the basket. Then the ad would animate through to the end where they would then click through to the client's website. It seems like it wouldn't be possible to click multiple times on a banner ad. Is this correct or is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A part of what you are describing should be doable using the `ExitApi`, which allows you to make only a specific part of your ad a clickable exit. It's not very well documented but mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6335681).

Note that there might be other Adwords policies which will prevent you from implementing your creative exactly as described, but having only a specific element in your ad triggering a click-through is possible.